# On row select (in p:dataTable) call different java methods?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, ajax4jsf

How to call different web services (different java methods) on row select in data table
and update the page asynchronous through ajax using row select.

I have this scenario because that i have 5 tabs should be updated by getting data from 5 methods. While 1st listener have not given data its effecting all anther tabs. so i want to call them separately.

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userController.onFetchUsers}" 
        update=":userRightPaneForm :usersForm:usersList"/>

<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userController.onFetchUserDetails}" 
        update=":userRightPaneForm :usersForm:usersList"/>
```

I have tried like this. But both `onFetchUsers` and `onFetchUserDetails` Method calling 2 times on row select event.

I am using Prime faces 3.4.2

How can i achieve it?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I have updated the question. Take a look.

Comment: Are you sure that you can register multiple ajax listeners for same event i PF? I have never seen this construction earlier.

Comment: Yes, I have 5 tabs should be updated by getting data from 5 methods. Because while 1st listener have not given data its effecting all anther tabs. so i want to call them separately.

Answer (score -1):

Its depends on the business scenario.

First of all one row select you can call java method which populate all tab the data and the in update give the ids of all five tabs sequentially.

Hope this work for you.

Or let me know exact scenario in terms of steps like tester and the problem.

Comment: Up to now i am using one method that populate data for all tab.
Now i want populate separately.